# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Tags: deep-learning, classification

i use this model

```
 model = Sequential([
        Dense(units=10, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'),
        Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
        Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')
    ])
   
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
    
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=30)
```

but model.fit always return this error

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported
> object type float).

however i converted my data as following

```
 x_train = np.array(x_train)
 y_train = np.array(y_train)
 x_test= np.array(x_test)
 y_test = np.array(y_test)
 y_train, x_train = shuffle(y_train, x_train)
 y_test, x_test = shuffle(y_test, x_test)
```

this is my model summary

[image]

and this is the shape of my data x_train as 1D of array  for each input sample, and y_train is a label for each sample and values from (1 to 10).

[image]

can any one helps me Regards in advance !

and i define my data as following

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

import io
dset = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['1-210.csv']))

y= dset.Readername
x=dset.drop('Readername',axis=1)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the model is expecting float input.  Try converting to float using **astype**:

X = np.asarray(X).astype(np.float32)

Comment: many thanks for your response i tried it, but i get this error
"could not convert string to float: '9 0.559884'"

Comment: Can you post your variable where you define the data?

Comment: OK i updated my question and defined my data over there really many thanks for your help

Comment: is your "y" a name?  I'm not sure how you can train a model to learn from "x" data to arrive at a particular string.   Maybe you should start a new thread explaining the problem you are trying to solve and get help in planning your model.

Comment: many thanks diylmma i used your answer and fixed the parameters of input_shape(), and finally it worked.but i have another problem i will make a new thread for it. Once again thank you very much !